# Can someone tell me a different way of writing this line of code?

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda

I know this is a strange question but for research purposes could anyone tell me a different way of writing this line of code? 
I am making a word cloud in The "forEach(s -> ignoreWords.add(s.toUpperCase()));" is the line of code I would like to change. Preferably not a lambda

Thanks very much in advance!!!!

Researched numerous pages

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
ignoreWords = new HashSet<String>(); 
 Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("/ignorewords.txt"));
stream.forEach(s -> ignoreWords.add(s.toUpperCase()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work?

```
Set<String> ignoreWords = Files.lines(Paths.get("/ignorewords.txt"))
                               .map(String::toUpperCase)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```